# Change in Hamiltonian under infinitesimal canonical transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Consider an infinitesimal canonical transformation from the (symplectic) coordinates $z$ with Hamiltonian $H(z, t)$, to the coordinates
$$
Z = z + \epsilon J \frac{\partial G}{\partial z}
$$
with the transformed Hamiltonian
$$
K(Z, t) = H(z(Z, t),t) +\epsilon \frac{\partial G(z(Z, t),t) }{\partial t}
$$
where $G = G(z, t)$ is the infinitesimal generator and $\epsilon$ is a small quantity. In the active view of this transformation, a point $A$ with coordinates $z$ is mapped to a different point $B$ with coordinates $Z$; in the passive view, $A$ is assigned new coordinates $A' \equiv Z $, but is physically unchanged.

I find it easy to see why the change in a function $u(z, t)$ under such a transformation is simply
$$
u(B) - u(A) = u(Z, t) - u(z, t) = u\left(z +\epsilon J\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}, t\right) -u(z, t) = \epsilon\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}J\frac{\partial G}{\partial z} = \epsilon\{u, G\},
$$
since this is just the change in the value of $u$ between the two points.

I get confused however, when it comes to the Hamiltonian. According to Goldstein $\S$9.6, the change in the Hamiltonian is
$$
\partial H = H(B) - K(A') = H(Z, t) - K(Z, t).
$$
Why is it defined in this way? I don't understand why the change isn't
$$
\partial H = K(B) - H(A) = K(Z, t) - H(z, t),
$$
since I would have thought that this would be the difference in the Hamiltonian before and after the transformation.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/537200/2451